# Bokeh: Wheel_Zoom with decoupled y-Axis

Tags: python, bokeh

I render a plot in Bokeh using two independent y-Axis:

```
    pAltitude = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=300, x_range=pElev.x_range)
    pAltitude.extra_y_ranges = {"speed": Range1d(50, 120)}
    pAltitude.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name="speed"), 'right')
```

When this plot is shown in the browser I can use the wheel_zoom tool to zoom in and out of the plot.When hovering the mouse over the x-axis, only the timescale is zoomed in and out, when hovering over one of the y-axis, only the y-scale is zoomed.

So far, so good: Is there a possibility to decouple the two y-axis for wheel zooming (and panning)?

I'd like to have only the ordinary y-axis zoomed when hovering over it and only the extra y-axis zoomed when hovering over that one.

Currently, both axis are coupled ad I cannot zoom or pan them individually.

Thanks a lot!

However

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not currently possible (as of version 1.4, and upcoming 2.0) to uncouple "twin" axes. Scaling one range will always scale the other by the same relative amount.

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Would be a great feature for future releases.